# Is it possible to kick user back to app after opening Safari link?

Tags: ios

I would like to provide iOS app developers with a way to redirect users to a URL on my site, and then to return users back to their app without knowing what it was, like a back button but across an action which opens a browser.

Two (preferred) requirements that are distinct from other questions:

- open in a window that both gets and persists login cookies to the browser of the user's choice
- return to arbitrary app

I understand that with a specific app, I can probably close the tab + do a deep link redirect on a tap handler. Is this possible with an arbitrary "close tab / switch to previous app", however?

Comment: Nope. Users don't like to _be returned_ by developer's wish... When you open a link from you app in Safari (or in any other app for that matter), users can tap the "back" button in the top right _when_ they wish.

Comment: The flow you described is commonly used in OAuth authentication; The app will provide a call-back URL to the website as a parameter.  Once authentication is complete the web site can open the app using the provided call-back URL.  It is, however, now preferred that this happens inside the app using `SFSafariViewController` rather by launching out to Safari.  There is no universal "open the previous app URL"

Comment: is there a way for `SFSafariViewController` to get / save cookies from / to the user's preferred browser? why is this preferred? whenever and app does this I have no way of telling whether it's phishing my gmail password!

Comment: Because `SFSafariViewController` is almost entirely out of your control.

Comment: It is preferred because it gives a nicer user experience; no jumping out to Safari and then back to your app.  The safari view controller shares cookies with the safari browser on the device. You know that it isn't stealing your password because you can see the URL and the lock at the top of the screen and copy the URL out if you want to double check

Comment: How do I know it’s the `SFSafariViewController`, not an identical looking custom `SFEvilSafariViewController`?